# format only subscript first letter (python)

Tags: python, string, format, letter

I have this symbolic variable below (b). For some reason only the first letter of the word 'front' appears in the subscript rather than the entire word.

Code:

a = 'front'

b = sym.symbols('\\theta{{A}}_{0}'.format(a))

Output:

where only the letter 'f' is appears in the subscript. I've tried the alternative of:

b = sym.symbols('\\theta{{A}}_{0}'.format({a}))

which subscripts the entire word but the word has inverted commas when being displayed. Could anyone provide some idea of why it's happening and how I could fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The string after formatting becomes:

```py
>>> a = "front"
>>> '\\theta{{A}}_{0}'.format(a)
'\\theta{A}_front'
```

Which should help explain the issue here. As you can imagine, this only turns the `f` into a subscript.

What you need is `'\\theta{{A}}_{{{0}}}'.format(a)`:

```py
>>> '\\theta{{A}}_{{{0}}}'.format(a)
'\\theta{A}_{front}'
```

In Python's format strings, `{0}` denotes the first place where a substitution can be performed with `.format`, while `{{` and `}}` simply become `{` and `}` respectively after using `.format`. Hence, you need `{{{0}}}.format(a)` to get `{front}` as output.

Comment: Thank you! That makes much more sense